# How to stop the screen from flickering right before jQuery's animate() executes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have noticed that right before my scroll-to-top animation takes place, the screen flickers.
This can be seen live at: http://www.dreamtheater.co.il

To recreate:

1. Scroll down until the menubar only remains at the top
2. Click on the right-most link from the menu

The HTML's body is like so: `<body id="top">`.
And the JavaScript (relevant code at the very bottom):

```
$(function() {
    var stickyHeader = $('#menubar').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeader) {
            ...
            ...
            $("a[href='http://www.dreamtheater.co.il/index/']").attr('href', '#top');
        } else {
            ...
            ...
            $("a[href='#top']").attr('href', 'http://www.dreamtheater.co.il/index/');
        }
    });

    $('#top').on("click",function() {
        $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow')
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it only in Chrome (based on tags), or in other browsers too? What OS?

Comment: Could you pass a url or a jsfiddle?

Comment: @ajp15243, I have tested only in Chrome thus far, maybe the tag is premature... OS is OS X.

Comment: @JoãoMosmann, can be seen in action here: http://www.dreamtheater.co.il

Comment: If possible, I would try in Chrome on non-OS X, and in other browsers. Since Chrome switched to the Blink engine in v28, there are probably going to be a few rare bugs. I do not see the issue in Chrome 29 on Linux.

Comment: Can't reproduce in latest chrome on win8

Comment: It's happening also in latest Safari, and it is WebKit-based...

Comment: It happens here. Win7 Chrome 29. But is sporadic. And when occur, just occur one time per page reload.

Comment: Just occur using the mouse wheel. If you drag browser scrollbar it doesn't bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, seems the problem was two-folded:

1. I pointed to `<body id="top">` instead to the href, which I also dynamically change on scroll
2. Did not 'release' the event

It now works smoothly, with no flickering, like this:

```
$("#menubar").on("click", "#menu a[href='#top']", function(){
    $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `return false`! Great!

Answer (score 1):

Well From what I understood. It's a problem from the recalculation of sizes and positioning of the elements.

I suggest you to put your #menu as position:absolute instead of position:static.

So, when you change your menu position css, from absolute to fixed, the browser will not need to recalculate the position and sizes of other elements,because the both position (absolute and fixed) are flying over the other elements, don't affecting then "phisically"

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't make the flickering disappear, and also ruined the default menu placement...

Comment: Yes, you need to positioning your menu at the right place using css. But it's strange, it should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the variant with the event variable is cleaner:

```
$("#menubar").on("click", "#menu a[href='#top']", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
});
```